# download file from site that uses session cookies with node

Tags: node.js, session-cookies, puppeteer, scrape, httponly

I'm trying to download a csv file from website that uses session cookies with HTTPOnly. I tried with request and using jar, and also tried with puppeteer (where the page is blocked from loading). I don't know if there is somthing I did wrong in the code, or is the whole method wrong...

The page is
https://data.gov.il/dataset/degem-rechev-wltp/resource/142afde2-6228-49f9-8a29-9b6c3a0cbe40

and the file is
https://data.gov.il/dataset/45e317cf-7bb1-4535-b8cf-be5e79ea341f/resource/142afde2-6228-49f9-8a29-9b6c3a0cbe40/download/degem_rechev_wltpmot.gov.il.csv

Any recommendations on how to download the file using node?

[image: Download button on page]

Answer (score -1):

On my box chrome developer tools generate next curl command

```
curl "https://data.gov.il/dataset/45e317cf-7bb1-4535-b8cf-be5e79ea341f/resource/142afde2-6228-49f9-8a29-9b6c3a0cbe40/download/degem_rechev_wltpmot.gov.il.csv" -H "authority: data.gov.il" -H "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1" -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36" -H "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3" -H "sec-fetch-site: none" -H "sec-fetch-mode: navigate" -H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "accept-language: en,ru-RU;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6,pl;q=0.5,de;q=0.4,fr;q=0.3" -H "cookie: rbzid=+y6YNWeSzY3HUYMml3AKWXon7IJJndSomjXuti1J3fMzCjkcRTkWcSnkKh2TVfpaN8fJxqFvvd8/of5JjfOwpHn7ZYzcg/QSp8JYjJdXlGfuNg5ihg05g576LXOCsl+HonH0UH6jxg2nfJK7wjKpJso3y5qA2g+n/bEWK3tCG0eGexT1ffDiGldR8wPawH2+McL0L9cyxAisd08BXJruqztVdXObV6h63o7Sb25Qu4ripVGOMhMat+ZWcV8GBkJG; rbzsessionid=75b0067c512d09569cc11db8a8f1b240" -H "if-none-match: W/^\^"1573792925.61-26103321^\^"" -H "if-modified-since: Fri, 15 Nov 2019 04:42:05 GMT" --compressed
```

I believe you can use it for create correct request from Node.js

Comment: Thanks, I managed to use curl like you showed here, but there is a "rbzid" cookie here, this is the key- On the first visit on site this cookie is created and I don't know how long will it be valid. So I would try to do it in 2 steps- first step to generate the rbzid cookie, and the second step would be a get requst/ CURL using the cookie from the previous step.